# Gnu Makefile, compile should fail

Tags: testing, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have a collection of examples that I want to **make sure they fail to compile**. What is the best way to to that with a **GNU Makefile*?

```
test_nocompile: $(NOCOMPILE_CPP)
    for cpp in $(NOCOMPILE_CPP) ; do \
        echo === $$cpp === ; \
        if $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o fail.o $$cpp ; then echo ok ; else exit 1; fi ; \
    done
```

As you can see, I have several difficulties here:

- Accessing the shell-for variable `cpp`: `$cpp`, `\$cpp` and `$$cpp` both do not work.
- Even with my `if` the make stops after the first g++-compile fails. But thats exactly what I want. I want failing to g++-compile to be considered the correct behaviour.
- Shell-for-loops in Makefiles are not the best idea. Is there a better way? I can not think of one, because since I expect the compiles to fail, I do not have a correct target, right?

Advanced and optional:

- If I could manage to have the *fail-check* above working, I could try a second pass of compilation, this time with an additional `-DEXCLUDE_FAIL`, which takes out the offending line from my examples, and then the code should compile. Any idea?
- or should write a Python script for that...? ;-)

**Edit:**

I think my "advanced and optional" gave me a very good idea right now. I could use makes dependency checking again. Just a rough sketch here:

```
 NOCOMPILE_CPP := $(wildcard nocompile/ *.cpp)
 NOCOMPILE_XFAILS := $(addsuffix .xfail,$(basename $(NOCOMPILE_CPP)))

 %.xfail: %.cpp
     if $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $< ; then exit 1 ; else echo OK ; fi
     $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DEXCLUDE_FAILCODE -o $@ $<

 test_nocompile: $(NOCOMPILE_XFAILS)
```

Is this elegant? Then I only have to work out how `-DEXCLUDE_FAILCODE` can make the failing tests work.... Non-trivial, but doable. I think that could do it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Works for me. What do you get in `echo`?
2. You need to negate the condition in `if` then. Right now it quits when the file doesn't compile and AFAIU you need the opposite.
3. Why it's not a good idea? But you can write a script that will call `$(CXX)` and return a proper error code (0 if it doesn't compile). Then you may have normal targets with this script. I'm not very good with specifics of GNU make, probably it's possible with the builtin stuff.

Advanced & optional:
1. Let's first make the thing work:)
2. Personally i don't use python, therefore don't see a need here =:P

Comment: Ahhh! Yes, I mis-corrected it before. Of course its the if. Prrrrr... *I thought with the "advanced option" I could may have the target-checks of make working again*... Wait, I will edit the question...

Comment: @towi: But as for the `-DEXCLUDE_FAIL` it's easily being done in the script. First check if it doesn't compile, exit if it does. Then check the compilation with define. The return code of the script shall be the return code of this command, that's what you need.

Comment: @towi: Why not `$(NOCOMPILE_CPP:.cpp=.xfail)`? You may also consider `! $(CXX)`, it shall negate the result and automatically quit when you need it → no need for if.

Comment: 1) `$(:.x=.y)` should also work, right. 2) I wasn't sure if `!` works in Makefiles as it does on a shell. I will try it out.

Comment: @towi: As the actions are executed in the shell, sure they do:)